# MVC Get data from multiple tables in database for specific user

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, view

I'm new to MVC, currently running MVC 2, done a lot av regular ASP.Net in the past.

**Background**
Have a database containing all the tables for the .Net Membership provider.
Created a table called "Lists" containing `UserID`, `ListID`, `ListName` and so on.
It has a relationship key to the .Net Membership User, UserID column.
There is also a "List_Items" table that has `ListID`, `ItemID`, `ItemName` and so on.

**What I have done**
I managed to create a Entity Data Model mapping to the database. It contains both tables.
In the view I have done this:

```
<ul>
 <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
   <li><a href="#<%= Html.Encode(item.ListID) %>"><%= Html.Encode(item.ListName) %></a></li>
 <% } %>
</ul>
```

In the controller I have done this:

```
private ToDoDBEntities _db = new ToDoDBEntities();
return View(_db.Todo_Lists.ToList());
```

This I got from the asp.net/mvc tutorials. This tells me to things... I get all the Lists for all users. And I don't get the List Items from the other table.

**What I want to do**
I want to be able to pass the Provider Userkey to the database, for the logged on user, so I only get's his/hers lists.
I also would like to get Lists table and List Items table to the view in the same call so I can build the UL/IL with the List. And build content divs with the List Items.

Happy for any input.

/K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What tutorial are you using? Because I highly recommend http://www.asp.net/mvc as a learning resource, follow the tutorials and it will show you how to do what you want. It will also teach you techniques that will make life easier for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have gotten a much better  understanding of MVC after checking the tutorials out!